# jQuery $.live() doesn't work with table rows on the iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, html-table, rows, live

I'm making table rows click-able with jQuery's `$.live()` function.
Works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and even desktop Windows Safari -- but not on the iPhone.
`$.bind()` works everywhere, but for obvious reasons I'd like to use the other function.

Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work and how can I fix it?
Example code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>test</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
 <style type="text/css">table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; } table tr {     background: #eee; } table td { padding: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }</style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.pack.js">        </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* $.bind() works */
  /*
  $('table').find('tr').bind('click', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  });
  */
  /* $.live() doesn't */
  $('table').find('tr').live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr><td>words are flying out \ </td><td>like endless rain into a paper cup</td></tr>
   <tr><td>they slither while they pass \ </td><td>they slip away across the             universe</td></tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with this code is that you're using `.live` wrong - it should be called directly on the selector:

```
$('table tr').live( /* ... */)
```

From the [specs](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> DOM traversal methods are not fully supported for finding elements to send to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector

Next, on jQuery 1.4.2, it's probably better to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('table').delegate('tr', 'click', function(){/* ... */} );
```