# html input button on a table doesn't call any jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table

```
<table style="width: 100%;" class='table_result'>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>text</td></tr>
</table>
```

Then when a button is clicked I call this

```
$("table.table_result").append('<tr class="topRow" style="height: 35px;">
                                  <td 'style="text-align: center; cursor: pointer">'+ text
                           +'</td><td style="text-align: center">'
                                  +'<input class="control_voteUp" type="button" value="Up">' 
                                  + text
                                  +'<input class="control_voteDown" type="button" value="Dn">' +'</td><td style="text-align: center">'+ text +'</td><td style="text-align: center">'+ text 
                           +'</td><td style="text-align: center">'+ text
                           +'</td><td style="text-align: center">'+ text +'</tr>');
```

So I want when `control_voteUp` is clicked to call a function.

I have tried the normal way and other with no succes:

```
$('input.control_voteUp').click(function()
{
    alert("aa");
}); 

$('input.control_voteUp').delegate('input', 'click', function()
{
   alert("aa");
});

$('input control_voteUp').live('click', function()
{
   alert("aa");
});
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your live function call you are missing a .

Change `input control_voteUp` to `input.control_voteUp`

Try:

```
$('input.control_voteUp').live('click', function()
{
   alert("aa");
});
```

Comment: Yeah it does work!! I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072441/jquery-live-doesnt-work-with-table-rows-on-the-iphone and it is without the dot, so I tried that way. My bad

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply the `delegate` call to an element that already exists, in this case the table:

```
$('table.table_result').delegate('input.control_voteUp', 'click', function() {
  alert("aa");
});
```